# Facebook API - Using 'limit' property to change paging limit in Python

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, python-2.7, scroll-paging

I'm using Python to access Facebook pages and retrieve information. When I try to retrieve the list of users who likes an item (ex: a post, a picture), i get only a partial list. I think this is due to paging limit. I know there is a way to change the paging limit in Facebook Graph:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[node]/likes?limit=1000
```

but I do not know how to implement the 'limit' property in Python code.

The code I use to gather the likes is:

```
import facebook
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)

profile = graph.get_object(page_id)
likes = str(profile.get('likes'))
```

Answer (score 0):

the above will get you the number of likes to the particular page. You can't get the list of fans of particular page. However you can check the if a particular user likes a page .

check the following page for all other common things that can be done with facebook graph api 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/common-scenarios